# Could I use Zxing for business purpose?

Tags: android, authorization, zxing

I got a app using zxing as core, I want to know, If I plus other functions to my app, Could I charge fee from users for the part I added. Thank you all guys.

Comment: They say: QR codes are free, full stop. If you're referring to the ultimate rights
holder for the technology, DensoWave -- they've long since stated that QR
code can be used freely. And the output of our project / encoder is not even
theoretically owned by anyone but you, so that image can be used as you
like. Nobody should be paying anything for QR codes, but, I know plenty of companies that are happy to receive a fee for encoding...http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/browse_thread/thread/a5b762342165a387

Comment: In documentary, it's so long, and I'm not very good at English.Thank you Rowland Shaw. How do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zxing is licenced under Apache licence so this link should fully answer your question:
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

So as I understand - yes, but you need to place notice in your app that you use Zxing and it's licensed under Apache licence

Comment: @AmyWuGo, best way to thank someone is by accepting the answer

Comment: Where could I chose accept? I thought chose "Was this post useful to you" Yes is the way to say accept. Would you please tell me how I should do.Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions

This is our statement on complying with the license. Yes, there is nothing prohibiting commercial or business use. License terms come into play when *distributing* the project's code.